# FlashDevelop is putting entire class path on new instance declaration

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop

This is more of a nuisance than anything, but when I use FlashDevelop and declare a new instance it puts the whole class path instead of just the class name.

For example I have a class called "FrameText" for a game I'm working on, it's located in the path "display.text.gameText.test.FrameText". I have an instance of type FrameText called "currentTask", and when I put `currentTask = new` the auto-prediction grabs the class FrameText since that's the instance type. I hit enter to accept that class and it puts

`currentTask = new display.text.gameText.test.FrameText`

instead of just `currentTask = new FrameText`. I've tried to look through the program settings to get it to stop putting the whole class path but I can't find anything.

Comment: It's randomly not doing this anymore. I don't know what I did but it seems to be okay now. I'm leaving the question open in case anyone knows what happened and how to prevent it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My brother figured it out (thanks homie), turns out I had two `FrameText` classes since I'm testing a text overhaul for my game. I renamed the test class to `FrameTextTest` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why. Nice that you figured it by yourself.

Comment: Yep! I'll leave this question up in case others have the same problem